# Cannot update/install RPM using yum on Red Hat Enterprise 7 - "Couldn't open file /root/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml"

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, repository

I have an RHEL OS running as a VM that my team wants to update two specific RPMS (the agent/program is already installed but is an outdated version, so we want to update).

I was having issues downloading the RPM using yum (pointed to the jfrog artifactory in the `MyRepo.repo` file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory), I kept getting `404 - Error not found errors`

So I decided to just use curl and download the RPMs manually to the VM. There are only (2) RPMs, one named something like `my-prog-app-8.0.rpm` and the other `my-prog-libs-8.0.rpm` in the `/root/rpms` directory I created.

NOW, my only issue is when I run something like:
`yum update my-prog-app` or `yum update my-prog-libs`, it fails each time with a failure like:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from MyRepo: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
file:///root/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /root/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml"
```

I'm not sure what the heck this `/repodata` directory or the `repomd.xml` file its looking for is. I did see this same error when I was trying to use yum to download the RPM by pointing to the artifactory in the `MyRepo.repo` file earlier. I figured I would be safe now because I have the RPMs locally and they are defined in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory as:

```
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/MyRepo.repo
[MyRepo]
name=My Local Repo
baseurl=file:///root/rpms
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Can anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong here? It can't be my connection/firewall issues, as the RPMs are already installed/downloaded/located locally on this OS (at `/root/rpms`) right?

what is this `/repodata/repod.xml`? How can I just update these (2) rpms?? or would I bet better off doing a fresh install with them or something?

Answer (score 2):

The `/repodata/repod.xml` is the main repository metadata file which `yum` expects any repository to have.

It's not clear why you simply didn't install update the downloaded RPMs directly via `rpm` or `yum`, but created a repo definition `/etc/yum.repos.d/MyRepo.repo` instead.

To make your repository work, you must use `createrepo /root/rpms`.
This will create repository metadata after scanning `.rpm` files in the directory.

Then your local repository will be usable by `yum`.

Comment: I said in my question why I simply didn't install update the RPMs.. I told you I get an "404 - Error Not found" everytime. "createrepo" doesn't work, it says "command not found". When I try to install "yum install createrepo" , it says "There are no enabled repos" Everywhere on google , tutorials said to create a .repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d

Comment: What I meant was - you downloaded RPMs already and they are in `/root/rpms`. Why not `rpm` install them? "There are no enabled repos" message would mean what it says. Have you removed all repo definitions from `/etc/yum.repos.d/` or otherwise disabled them?

Comment: @Danilla Vershinin This is at my company. We build up a VM (virtual machine) from a RHEL (Red Hat Linux 7) .iso using a bunch of shell/bash scripts. I am trying to upgrade 2 things from a BIG package of applications that we install using "yum install...." in one of the .sh scripts.....

So like, "yum install -y app-A app-B app-C app-D app-E app-F app-G .....app-X app-Y" 

app-X and app-Y are installed already on this VM but I am trying to update them. I thought "yum" would be the easiest option but its turned to be hell. I just tried "rpm -U" and "rpm -i" and I'm getting errors also...

Comment: ..... All the apps A through G come from a big artifactory (jfrog), but they don't have the newest version of app-X and app-Y, that's why I am trying to "point" or "add" this new repo to "update" these new versions of app-X and app-Y that are already installed.... but its definitely not that simple as I think there are dependencies involved (I didn't build this application but I'm am just trying to solve this and having a hard time)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2882769f830026847c870ffbf4b1e17d That's me trying "rpm -i" and upgrade... I think it's because it doesn't have the dependencies for RPM? but "yum " solves this? that's why I was trying to use yum...

Comment: Is there anyway to manually generate the repodata file /metadata without installation "yum install createrepo" ?

Answer (score 0):

figured this out. needed to point to baseurl where `/repodata/repomd.xml/` file was located.